# Linking to content within MS Word file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

On a MS Word document I've multiple Q&As. This file is saved as a stored document in Sharepoint. Can I create a link on a Sharepoint page that will take a user to a specific answer within that MS Word file? Not a link to just a page within the MS Word file but an actual answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Online, you can create a link to specific page number.

1. Click on the "..." button beside your document -> Copy Link
2. At the end of copied link, add `&action=embedview&wdStartOn=3` which `3` is the page number of your document
3. Test the link (url)

I would like the feature to jump to a bookmark but it seems no.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test currently this feature is not supported on word side.

If we add a hyperlink likes "http://site/shareddocuments/xx.doc/#Job" in SharePoint page to open the special location in the word client, it will open the whole document instead of the bookmark section.

In other words, if we use word online, it does not support creating hyperlinks (bookmarks or cross references) to other places in the same document.

So it will not work in SharePoint either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use make bookmarks in Word Document and save it on SharePoint. Then link to that bookmark. The process is bit tricky. The url should have the bookmark name as parameter.

The link below might be useful.

https://www.success-trending.club/2020/03/linking-to-bookmark-in-word-document.html